# break y axis in line chart chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to render a line graph with two datasets
My sample chart

```
 <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
             datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'My First dataset',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    fill: false,
                    data: [9000, 9020, 9010, 9004, 9011, 9040, 9050]
                },
                {
                    label: 'My Second dataset',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(0, 99, 132)',
                    fill: false,
                    data: [1000, 1020, 1010, 1004, 1011, 1040, 1050]
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        stepSize: 10
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

This is how it looks currently [current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWGHg.png)

This the graph will be easy to read if it has axis break like this
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv4vB.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in way to do this. The best thing you can do is use a second Y axes and link the second dataset to the other axes.

```
datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1,
        yAxisID: 'first'
        },  
            {
                label: '# of Points',
                data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
                borderWidth: 1,
        yAxisID: 'second'
            }
        ]

options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        id: 'first'
      },{
        id: 'second'
      }]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes I thought of that, but that will not help when I scale to 2+ datasets.

Comment: Kind of, if you calculate if there is a scale already on which it can match. Otherwise maby think about the data you are showing because it doesn't sound logical to have so many datasets from different orders of magnitude. But if you really want a broken axis you will need to write your own one (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html)

Comment: The usecase I am trying to solve is to graph an order management. For example the datasets would be orders fulfilled (1000+ per day), orders pending (100+ per day), orders cancelled(5+ per day) across a week. But ya I do see the limitations